# Transformar txt a JSON

Tags: php, json

Tengo un listado de ciudades en un archivo txt con su respectivo nombre de ciudad y su id, deseo transformarlo a JSON con un formato:

```
[{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"CIUDAD_NOMBRE","ID_CIUDAD":"CIUDAD_ID"}].
```

Lo que actualmente tengo en el txt es:

```
"CIUDAD_NOMBRE" "CIUDAD_ID".
```

Observación: CIUDAD_NOMBRE Y CIUDAD_ID, corresponden a algún nombre de ciudad y un id.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto en PHP?

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $json_data = file_get_contents('listadoComunasMarquee.txt');
        //json_decode($json_data, true);
        echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Pero desconozco como darle el formato que requiero, porque me queda así.

[image: Imagen JSON con caracteres]

Dejo algunas ciudades con su respectivo Id.

```
OSORNO      104001
COYHAIQUE   114401
PUNTA ARENAS    124901
LAS CONDES  132130
LA PINTANA  132119
RENCA       132108
COLINA      132001
CASTRO      104201
```

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta, introduciendo lo que me preguntas.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo tienes casi hecho, apenas falta un par de pasos intermedios. Ahora ando algo liado, pero te escribo una respuesta en un rato si nadie lo hace antes.

Comment: Oka,  muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes. Sólo te faltarían un par de pasos intermedios:

1. Romper la cadena leída por salto de línea (`\n`)
2. Cada elemento romperlo por tabulador (`\t`)
3. Crear un array asociativo para darle nombre a cada valor

El código quedaría así y ya funcionaría:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_data = file_get_contents('listadoComunasMarquee.txt');
// separamos el fichero en lineas (\n)
$json_data = preg_split( "/\n/", $json_data );
// para cada elemento
for ($x = 0; $x < count($json_data); $x++) {
    // lo separamos por tabulador (\t)
    $dupla = preg_split("/\t/", $json_data[$x], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    // sustituimos el elemento por un array asociativo similar
    $json_data[$x] = array(
        "NOMBRE_CIUDAD" => $dupla[0],
        "ID_CIUDAD" => $dupla[1]
    );
}
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, pero tengo algunos problemas.

En ciertas ciudades no está leyendo el nombre y el id, queda así:

{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"RENCA ","ID_CIUDAD":""},{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"COLINA ","ID_CIUDAD":""},{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"CASTRO ","ID_CIUDAD":""},{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"","ID_CIUDAD":null},{"NOMBRE_CIUDAD":"","ID_CIUDAD":null}]

En específico desde esta ciudad está el problema:

LA PINTANA  132119
RENCA   132108
COLINA   132001
CASTRO  104201

Esas 4 ciudades las muestra con problemas

Comment: @Rodrigo Ok. Yo he usado un fichero propio basándome en la imagen que compartiste, pero si pones un ejemplo específico podré ayudarte mejor. Edita la pregunta y copia unas líneas del fichero txt (no todo entero) a la publicación.

Comment: Oka, agregué algunas ciudades, principalmente las que tienen problemas.

Comment: Ok. Ya veo el problema: la cosa es que la separación entre nombre de ciudad e ID de ciudad puede ser de más de un tabulador. Voy a editar la respuesta, porque además, `split` no debería usarse porque está anticuada.

Comment: @Rodrigo Prueba ahora, la solución usa `preg_split` que permite descartar los campos vacíos (causados por múltiples tabuladores entre nombre e id)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ahora si quedó bien. Saludos.

Comment: Nose si hacer otra pregunta o modificar la misma, pero ahora lo que ocurre es que necesito capturar el valor de la clave "ID_CIUDAD", para luego pasarlo a una query dentro de la misma funcion de php

Comment: @Rodrigo Podrías hacer `$dupla[1]` si quieres capturar el valor dentro del bucle; o si lo quieres fuera, sería algo como `$json_data[indice]["ID_CIUDAD"]` (donde índice sería el índice del registro que quieres usar)

Comment: entiendo lo que me dices, muchas gracias. Pero me sigue apareciendo un error, es mejor que modifique mi pregunta dejando el código que tengo?

Comment: Creo que eso sería más otra pregunta porque es un error nuevo.

Comment: Listo, hice una nueva pregunta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124508/query-en-php-con-datos-desde-txt

Saludos y muchas gracias.